# How do I join 3 tables with 2 different ids (sql in snowflake)?

Tags: join, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

First, I need to unzip data from one table to transform into a new table. Secondly, I need to join another table to this new table based on customer id Z. Thirdly, I need to join yet another table to that second table using a different customer id, customer id Y.

Part 1: I have this data from Table A below.

| NAME (Column 1) | VALUE (Column 2) | Customer_idZ (Coulmn 3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| account_status | ACTIVE | 1234 |
| card_template | Rewards | 1234 |
| customer_creation_date | 1/8/2022 | 1234 |
| enroll_store_code | pxweb | 1234 |
| enroll_store_name | Web Site | 1234 |
| push_opt_in | Yes | 1234 |

I am transforming this data from Table A into a new table formatted as the below with this code

```
'''SELECT
Customer_idZ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'account_status' THEN VALUE END) AS account_status,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'card_template' THEN VALUE END) AS card_template,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'customer_creation_date' THEN VALUE END) AS customer_creation_date,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_code' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_code,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_name' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'push_opt_in' THEN VALUE END) AS push_opt_in
 FROM Table A
GROUP BY Customer_idZ;
```

| Customer_idZ | account_status | card_template | customer_creation_date | enroll_store_code | enroll_store_name | push_opt_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ACTIVE | PX Rewards | 1/8/2022 | pxweb | Web Site | Yes |

Part 2: I want to then join another table (Table B) to this this newly formatted data based on the shared customer_idZ field. The data in Table B is below;

| Customer_idZ | Status | Customer_idY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ACTIVE | 567890 |

Part 3: I need to join another table (Table C) to Table B based on the shared Customer_idY field. The data in Table C is below;

| Customer_idY | Household_size | Children_present_in_household |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 567890 | 6 | Yes |

Final: I need the final output solely to be a list of customer_idY and customer_idZ.

I am not sure how to structure the multi-join needed between the three tables and need to pull ids for those profiles that have active status' in table a and have household sizes of 4 or more

Comment: How do you want to handle records that exist in A but not B or in B but not in C or in C but not in B... etc..

Comment: digging into it more, I am realizing I only want the records where the status is active in table a and the household size is greater than 4 in table c

Answer (score 0):

I'm ussing a common table expression (CTE) "NEWA" to reformat your "A" table... we could make this an inline view but I find a CTE easier to read

We may need to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` depending on how you want to handle when related records are not in associated tables...

```
With NewA As (SELECT
Customer_idZ,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'account_status' THEN VALUE END) AS account_status,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'card_template' THEN VALUE END) AS card_template,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'customer_creation_date' THEN VALUE END) AS customer_creation_date,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_code' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_code,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_name' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'push_opt_in' THEN VALUE END) AS push_opt_in
 FROM Table A
GROUP BY Customer_idZ)

SELECT Cusotmer_idZ
     , Customer_idY
     , account_status
     , card_template
     , customer_creation_date
     , enroll_store_code
     , enroll_store_name
     , push_opt_in
     , Household_size
     , Children_present_in_household
FROM NewA A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.Customer_idZ= B.Customer_idZ
INNER JOIN C
 on B.Customer_IDY = C.Customer_IDY
WHERE Household_size >= 4
  and account_status='Active'
```

We then use common join syntax to join on the relationships between the tables.

Now we could make these outer joins if you want all records from A and only those that match from B and all records from A combine b and those related records in C.

or we could use full outer joins to return all records from all tables.  just depends on what you're after.

We could also use an inline view instead of a CTE:

```
SELECT A.Cusotmer_idZ
     , B.Customer_idY
     , account_status
     , card_template
     , customer_creation_date
     , enroll_store_code
     , enroll_store_name
     , push_opt_in
     , Household_size
     , Children_present_in_household
FROM (SELECT
      Customer_idZ,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'account_status' THEN VALUE END) AS account_status,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'card_template' THEN VALUE END) AS card_template,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'customer_creation_date' THEN VALUE END) AS customer_creation_date,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_code' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_code,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_name' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'push_opt_in' THEN VALUE END) AS push_opt_in
      FROM Table A
      GROUP BY Customer_idZ) A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.Customer_idZ= B.Customer_idZ
INNER JOIN C
 on B.Customer_IDY = C.Customer_IDY
WHERE Household_size >= 4
  and account_status='Active'
```

Comment: I am realizing I just need a list of both ID Y and ID Z with a filter for only if the household size is 4 or more. How would I add that in?

Comment: How do you determine the household size , is it this column  Household_size , if yes then you can filter Household_size >= 4

Comment: for some reason I'm getting an identified error regarding a.customer_idZ here FROM NewA A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.CustomerIDZ = B.CustomerIDZ

Comment: Needed the underscores between customer_IDz & Customer_IDY on queries.  corrected

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the column names in the query by @xQbert and hope it helps.

```
SELECT A.Customer_idZ
     , B.Customer_idY
     , account_status
     , card_template
     , customer_creation_date
     , enroll_store_code
     , enroll_store_name
     , push_opt_in
     , Household_size
     , Children_present_in_household
FROM (SELECT
      Customer_idZ,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'account_status' THEN VALUE END) AS account_status,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'card_template' THEN VALUE END) AS card_template,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'customer_creation_date' THEN VALUE END) AS customer_creation_date,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_code' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_code,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'enroll_store_name' THEN VALUE END) AS enroll_store_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'push_opt_in' THEN VALUE END) AS push_opt_in
      FROM  A
      GROUP BY Customer_idZ) A
INNER JOIN B
 on A.Customer_idZ = B.Customer_idZ
INNER JOIN C
 on B.Customer_idY = C.Customer_idY;
```